# How much of a performance hit is there when calling async methods that are immediately waited on?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, async-await

A lot of API's are moving toward exposing only asynchronous methods.  How much of a performance hit is there in scenarios where you have to immediately wait on these methods?  Am I wrong in assuming that it causes the current thread to wait on a spawned thread to complete?  Or does the CLR perform some sort of magic in these scenarios and make it all execute in the same thread?

Comment: Do you mean blocking wait, i.e. `task.Wait()`, or asynchronous "wait", i.e. `await task`?

Comment: `task.Wait()`. The method in which I'm doing this can't call `await` because it can't be made `async`.

Comment: Why are you calling a async method then? is there no sync version to call? Please show us how you are starting the async method as on depending on how it is started different things can happen.

Comment: Usually if you use `async/await`, the whole chain of calls should be made async. You would block with `Wait` on the top level, e.g. in the  `Main` of a console app. Where exactly you'd block (if you should at all) depends on your code execution environment.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain  There is no sync version to call.  The first sentence of my question kinda implies that.

Answer (score 3):

By "asynchronous methods", I assume you mean `Task<T>` based async methods.

So if you have a method that returns a `Task<T>` and you immediately call its `Wait()` method, that causes the current that to wait on an internal `WaitHandle` object. The task most likely executes on a different thread and signals the `WaitHandle` when completed, which releases the waiting thread. There is no compliler optimization that turns this scenario into a synchronous call that I'm aware of.

This is of course more work than just calling a synchronous equivalent of the async method. However,depending on your use case, it probably won't be a significant difference.

The more important question is why would you want to loose the advantages of async by blocking the calling thread? That is generally not a good idea, you should ensure you have a very good reason to do this.

Comment: This is a scenario where there is no choice but to immediately wait on the task.  Specifically, I'm doing this in `Application_PostAuthenticateRequest` in `Global.asax`.

Comment: @w.brian, my experience is limited in this area, but I think you can use `async` tasks inside ASP.NET 4.5 event handlers via `RegisterAsyncTask`, [more details](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheMagicOfUsingAsynchronousMethodsInASPNET45PlusAnImportantGotcha.aspx).

Comment: Actually, it seems that `Task` doesn't use any `WaitHandle`, it uses `ManualResetEventSlim`. But that's not a big difference.